# How to safely dispatch code after delay on the main thread, using GCD?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

Is it safe to dispatch a block of code with delay on the main thread, if you are already on the main thread?

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), theBlock);
```

Or is there a safer way? Do I have to perform any checks if I am already on main queue (main thread) when executing this?

Comment: It's not `greatest-common-divisor`, it's `grand-central-dispatch`, I believe.

Comment: Yes. No. You may want to use weakSelf to avoid retaining an out of date view controller etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generally don't have to check whether you're already on the main thread if the block is enqueued asynchronously, [which `dispatch_after` does](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW3):

> This function waits until the specified time and then asynchronously adds block to the specified queue.

You would have to check however, if you were using a synchronous function like `dispatch_sync`. That would otherwise result in a deadlock.

Comment: I'm calling the above code simply from the main thread (after user presses a button). Can you give an example with dispatch_sync that causes a deadlock?

Comment: dispatch_get_current_queue is deprecated.

Comment: You can use `[NSThread isMainThread]` instead of `dispatch_get_current_queue` (obviously only for the main thread queue).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe. There are other ways to perform actions on main thread, but I don't guess they are safer. You can use, for example:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: YOUR_BLOCK_HERE ];
```

I really prefer NSOperationQueue when the extra features of GCD are not needed. It is easier.